# Admin user can't administer the site

Tags: debugging

When I sign with admin user (or any other user), I can edit the contents, I can edit user, I can´t create user, I can`t Edit nodes, I can´t install upgrades, I can´t install modules, I can´t save anything.

Thanks.

Comment: First do  you check privileges of your user. Second try to see what system log is recording if there is nothing see what php error log or server error log is recording you may have some file/folder/database permission problems.

Comment: Please note, Drupal Answers isn't a debug service. Often problems like these require access to your environment. All people can do guess what you're asking and what might be causing your problem.

Comment: Check your permissions .

Answer (score 0):

If you can't do all that with the superuser (typically admin, user ID 1), checking permissions won't help, since that account has a "pass all permissions" check on nodes, modules, users, etc.

To figure this out, you can try a few things:

- Go into the database and check if your admin user really has uid 1 (in the users table)
- Check modules (custom modules, specifically) to see if any of them deny access to any admin pages